# Free WYSIWYG DITA editor

Tags: gratis, xml, wysiwyg

[DITA (Darwin Information Typing Architecture)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_Information_Typing_Architecture) has a document fragment format.

I am looking for a free DITA editor in WYSIWYG mode.

Requirements:

- [What you see is what you get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG)
- Supports all concepts: topics, maps, specialization
- Very reliable, never crashes
- User-friendly
- Free
- Can run at least on Windows, webapps OK